# Does this violate the "Dependency Inversion Principle"?

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependency-inversion

```
public class Connection {
public Connection(){

}

public String description() {
    return "Generic";
}
```

}

```
public class SqlServerConnection extends Connection{


public SqlServerConnection(){

}

public String description(){
    return "SQL Server";
}
```

}

```
public class OracleConnection extends Connection{
public OracleConnection(){

}

public String description(){
    return "Oracle";
}
```

}

```
public class MySqlConnection extends Connection{
public MySqlConnection(){

}

public String description(){
    return "MySQL";
}
```

}

```
public class FirstFactory {
String type;

public FirstFactory(String t){
    type = t;
}

public Connection createConnection(){
    if(type.equals("Oracle")){
        return new OracleConnection();
    }else if(type.equals("SQL Server")){
        return new SqlServerConnection();
    }else{
        return new MySqlConnection();
    }
}
```

}

```
public class TestConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
        FirstFactory factory;

        factory = new FirstFactory("Oracle");

        Connection connection = factory.createConnection(); //createConnection return concrete implementation not an abstraction

        System.out.println("You're connection with " + connection.description());
}
```

}

This is from VTC design pattern video tutorials my question is did this example violates the Dependency Inversion Principle?

Because TestConnection class depends on concrete implementation because factory.createConnection() return concrete implementation not an abstraction.

can I fix this by doing this instead?

```
public Connection createConnection(){

Connection connection = null;

if(type.equals("Oracle")){
    connection = new OracleConnection();
}else if(type.equals("SQL Server")){
    connection = new SqlServerConnection();
}else{
    connection = new MySqlServerConnection();
}
return connection;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would inject the factory into the TestConnection (i.e. it would take a ConnectionFactory as a parameter, by an interface) rather than calling "new" to get a factory.  That way the TestConnection doesn't depend either on the concrete implementation of the Factory or of the Connection.

It's fine that the factory returns a concrete implementation of Connection -- in fact, it's necessary if you want to actually use the connection. You aren't depending on the *particular* concrete implementation because the factory returns it as Connection (i.e. as the interface).  Someone, somewhere does have to actually instantiate the Connection implementation -- that's the job of a Factory.

It would be a violation if, say, the OracleConnection had certain methods that other connections don't, and the calling class was depending on those.  Not the case here.

Comment: But you are depending on a Factory that is depending on all the concrete implementations of Connection. To add a new database you'd have to modify the Factory. That violates the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Comment: In my book, that's exactly the job of a factory -- to wrap and abstract away the actual building of concrete implementations.  The concrete implementations aren't a dependency for the factory, however, because it isn't using them.  It's just creating them.  Someone has to create them.  Sure, you can use Spring or another dependency injection framework, but that is simply a species of Factory.

Comment: Yes, Jacob,  the job of a factory is to wrap and abstract away the actual building of concrete implementations.  But it still violates violates the Dependency Inversion Principle if the code **using** the factory depends on a **concrete** implementation of a Factory.  In addition, `FirstFactory` requires it be constructed with the a string indicating the type of the database to create connections for. Thus the high-level module is depending on a low-level module and the abstraction is depending on a detail.  2 violations of the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Answer (score 1):

While it can be argued that your general architecture is not the best way to go about implementing database connections, I'll skip that as I understand the question to be more about Dependency Inversion rather than database implementation.  To achieve full Dependency Inversion:

- `Connection` should be an interface, not a concrete class.
- `ConnectionFactory` should be an interface, not a concrete class, that defines a `createConnection()` method returning a `Connection`.  It should not require arguments in its constructor.
- For each database, you would have a different concrete class that implements `ConnectionFactory` and returns objects that implement `Connection`.

The above satisfies the Dependency Inversion Principle better because now TestConnection only specifies what it needs from service providers and is not coupled to any concrete implementation.  Any concrete implementation can be created and used so long as it meets the requirements specified by the interfaces defined for TestConnection and the interfaces specify no more than what TestConnection truly needs.

In particular, another vendor in another package can create a new `Factory` and `Connection` implementation and you can plug that into the code (if you've followed the above architecture) and your `TestConnection` class needs no modification of any kind.

This supports many paradigms of run-time association of concrete services to service clients.  For example, in a typical Startup-time Dependency Injection scenario, you would inject a concrete implementation of `ConnectionFactory` into `TestConnection` and it would then look like:

```
public class TestConnection {
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    public setConnectionFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        this.connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //
        // Perform dependency injection here
        //

        // after dependency injection

        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection(); //createConnection return concrete implementation not an abstraction

        System.out.println("You're connection with " + connection.description());
    }
}
```

This separates TestConnection completely from any dependency on any database and makes it easily configurable by injecting just a `ConnectionFactory`.   Alternately, instead of "Perform dependency injection" you could do a service lookup.  J2EE/J3EE use this extensively, for example to get a ConnectionFactory (or more typically a `DataSource`) out of the JNDI `Context` object.  These are beyond the scope of the question, and just provided as an example of why you would want to do this and one way to check if you've satisfied the principle.  `TestConnection` should only be referring to Interfaces, not Classes, for anything that is coming from external sources (such as Database drivers).

Comment: This looks like dependency injection.  While often used in conjunction, i believe dependency inversion principle to be a different pattern.

Comment: @Bruce, I will clarify the answer, but in short, the top bullet points describe how to architect the solution to conform to the Dependency Inversion principle and the rest shows an example of how you would use it and what benefit it will provide.  For my example, I chose Dependency Injection, but you could just as easily craft an example using a Service Locator or Plug-in Configuration.

Answer (score 0):

the Dependency Inversion Principle principals are

A - High-level modules should not depend on low-level modules. Both should depend on abstractions.

In your case you've got the Connection abstracted which is good.  The use of the factory pattern is fine in my opinion too.

B - Abstractions should not depend upon details. Details should depend upon abstractions.

Your Connection does not depend on lower implementations, and the inherited classes may use methods/variables of Connection (if the example was more complex they probably would)

As an aside, I would lean towards making the Connection an abstract class though, if you were to add some more functionality to it later, and not bother with the default constructor which is made for you

```
public class Connection {
  public abstract String description();
}
```

or just make it an interface

```
public interface Connection {
  String description();
}
```

Comment: But Bruce, the Factory, a high-level abstraction, depends on all the low-level modules. To add a new database you'd have to modify the Factory.  That violates the Dependency Inversion Principle.

Answer (score -1):

The two `createConnection` implementations you propose are equivalent; there's no functional difference between direction returning a connection versus stashing the connection in a variable and returning that.

As to whether there is some violation of dependency inversion going on, I would say that the factory is sort-of fine, depending on how it is intended to be used. What you want is for classes to take a `Connection` as a parameter, rather than having a factory that it calls directly to obtain a connection.

Comment: I store the connection into its interface so maybe I assume its program to interface. So maybe Im wrong.

Comment: You really want Connection to be an interface, not a class.  You don't want other providers to be forced to extend your Connection class.